# DNS not resolving through db.cache enteries

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

i m facing a problem in which mine DNS server is not resolving via db.cache eatery.
i want to revolve xxxx.mnc019.mcc502.gprs via y.y.y.y ip (db.cache) but it is getting resolved via x.x.x.x ip ( forwarder ip).

please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Config given below

```
*cat /etc/named.conf 

options {
        directory "/etc/named.data";
        forwarders      {       x.x.x.x;      };
};
.....
..
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "db.cache";
...
...
..*

*cat /etc/named.data/db.cache

; .             99999999        IN      NS      root.server.
; root.server.  99999999        IN      A       ??.??.??.??
;
.       99999999        IN      NS      mnc019.mcc502.gprs.
mnc019.mcc502.gprs.     99999999        IN      A      y.y.y.y*
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.` zone is specified as the `hint` type (which is what the zone type for the root hints should be for a normal DNS server on the internet).

Since you want to use that file as authoritative, you'll need to set the type to `master`, but keep in mind this will prevent any forwarding to internet name servers from taking place anymore, since you're telling your BIND server that's it's authoritative for the root.

Why not just create a zone for `gprs` instead?